# How do i pass a variable to a nested function?

Tags: javascript, createjs

I have recently started to use createjs and have come to this problem (which doesnt have anything t odo with createjs):

```
for (a in ship.weapon) {

    //code
    button[a].addEventListener("click", function() {

        ship.weapon[a].amount = ship.weapon[a].amount.plus(1);
    });
    //code
}
```

The "a" variable will ofcourse at the time that the button is pressed be the lenght of the ship.weapon array. So how do i make it so that the "a" inside the click function will stay at the value of the for loop when it was made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a closure to freeze the `a` value

```
for (a in ship.weapon) {

    (function(index) {
        button[index].addEventListener("click", function() {

            ship.weapon[index].amount = ship.weapon[index].amount.plus(1);
        });
    })(a); // calls the function I just defined passing 'a' as parameter
}
```

Comment: i like this one thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use a function for this, there is no other way.

```
function addEvent(a) {
   //code
   button[a].addEventListener("click", function() {
     ship.weapon[a].amount = ship.weapon[a].amount.plus(1);
   });
   //code
}

for (var a in ship.weapon) {
  addEvent(a);
}
```

This will work.